# Is an SEM the correct choice in this case?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, medicine

I want to do some research about how having one specific disease affects the well-being of people. Therefore, I have disease as my independent variable and well-being as the dependent one. In between, there are many mediating and moderating variables such as depression and self-esteem that are neagtively affected by the disease and which influence the people's well-being. Those mediating and moderating variables intercorrelate as well. There already is a lot of reserach on how having the disease affects e.g. depression and self-esteem and different research on how depression and self-esteem affects the well-being so that I could draw a theoretial model from that. However, it is still unclear how those mediating and moderating variables interact and how big their individual influence on the well-being is.
To change that, I'd  like do an Structural Equation Model so that I can graphically show in the end how all variables interact and how big their individual influences are. All in all, I'd have about 9 mediating and moderating variables like depression, anxiety, ADHD, living situation and so on.

My questions now are the following:

1) Can I use a SEM in this case or do I have to many interacting mediating variables?

2) Would you suggest using any other statistics instead?

3) Would it be correct to first build two independendant SEMs for the disease and non-diesease group and then to combine those two in a next step?

Any comments or help is very much appreciated; thank you in advance!

Comment: I guess one of the biggest problems might be my sample size: I only have 200-300 participants in the disease group. With that it might be impossible to have that many paths?

Answer (score 0):

[Structural equation modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_equation_modeling) is useful for problems where one must analyze two things:

- Structural model: identifies potential causal relationships between endogenous and exogenous variables, and
- Measurement model: identifies relationships between latent variables (hypothetical constructs) and their indicators (operationalized measurements)

More detail is required to provide a more specific answer to your question, but in any analysis, [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) is relevant. Use the least complicated form of analysis that allows you to establish a null hypothesis and the conditions under which it would be rejected.

Regarding your sample size question, it is advisable to conduct a statistical power analysis to determine the minimum sample size required to effectively discern an effect of a particular magnitude. See [Sample Size Requirements for Structural Equation Models: An Evaluation of Power, Bias, and Solution Propriety](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4334479/) for additional background on this topic.